# Can I turn this button with animation into pure CSS for Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, button, css-animations

I have been asked to apply this button effect to all the buttons on a wordpress site. When looking at the code it isn't all CSS. Some of the code is part of the HTML that drives the animation (there is an SVG in there).

Additionally, it is set for 180px wide exactly and isn't responsive. This won't work for all links.

Any idea how I can apply something similar with all CSS so I can apply a class to it and have it work on an existing link? I don't quite understand what is happening.

[Code Pen Link of Button](https://codepen.io/vitor-siqueira/pen/xNBExN)

[image: GIF of Button]

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="center">
  <button class="btn">
    <svg width="180px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 180 60" class="border">
      <polyline points="179,1 179,59 1,59 1,1 179,1" class="bg-line" />
      <polyline points="179,1 179,59 1,59 1,1 179,1" class="hl-line" />
    </svg>
    <span>HOVER ME</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  A quick google surfaces quite a few pure css examples very similar to this.

Comment: I googled and only found solutions that have additional HTML code. I'm open to also using javascript. But, apparently, I don't know what to google for.

Answer (score 1):

Since your svg is used as a background element that should fill the whole button area, you'll need relative and absolute positions:

The parent `<button>` element needs a `position:relative` property.
The child `<svg>` (.border) is absolutely positioned:

```
.border {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

It will be stretched to the full width and height to it's parent element.

It also needs a `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute. Otherwise the polyline would keep its 180/60 aspect ratio.

#### Example

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #5ca4ea;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}


.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #91c9ff;
    outline: none;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover {
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    background: #4f95da;
}

.btn:hover .border {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 0;
}


.border {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width:2px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover .borderRect{
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;   
}

.borderRect{
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform-origin:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60" class="border" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <polyline pathLength="100" points="179,1 179,59 1,59 1,1 179,1" class="bg-line" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
        </svg>
        HOVER ME
    </button>

  <button class="btn">
    <svg class="border borderRect">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" pathLength="100"  stroke-width="12" />
    </svg>
         Very very long button text (using rect)
    </button>
</div>
```

[`<vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect) will prevent unequal stroke-widths on scaled elements.

**Alternative:** Use a `<rect>` element instead.
svg primitives can use percentages as units – no need for a `viewBox` or a `preserveAspectratio` rule:

```
<svg class="border borderRect">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" pathLength="100"  stroke-width="12" />
</svg>
```

See also [css tricks:Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)